# Why jquery then callback is running before deferred is resolved?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a load more ajax function. However, whenever the button is clicked, it runs the function inside then() before deferred object is resolved. I had to use setTimeout in then to make it work. I don't think this is a correct way since it makes then() completely meaningless ? Can anyone take a look what's going on please? Thanks.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.c-button--lg', function() {

            var appendHTML = function () {
                var $dfd = $.Deferred();
                $.get(nextLink, function(html) { 
                    $pillarContainer.append(html); 
                    console.log(0);
                    $dfd.resolve();
                });
                return $dfd.promise();
            };

            appendHTML().then(function(){ 
                console.log(1); //This is running before console.log(0);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your code defines a function named `appendHTML()`, but calls a function named `appendData()`.  Thus, we have no idea what `appendData()` actually is.  In addition, you should just return the promise that `$.get()` already returns.  There is no reason to use the [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of creating a new deferred here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define `appendHTML`, but call `appendData()` in your code example, it is not clear what `appendData()` in your code actually does.

If you meant for `appendHTML` and `appendData` to be the same function name in your question, then you can vastly simplify what you have like this and also avoid the [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of wrapping an existing promise in another unnecessary promise/deferred (and also avoid the bugs you introduced by doing that because you don't have proper error handling).  And, it should not have the problem you report either.

This code just returns the promise that `$.get()` already returns and it uses that promise to process the result so you're consistently using promises (not mixing promises with custom jQuery callbacks):

```
   $(document).on('click', '.c-button--lg', function () {

       // define $pillarContainer somewhere in here

       function appendData() {
           return $.get(nextLink).then(function(html) {
               $pillarContainer.append(html);
               console.log(0);
               return html;
           });
       };

       appendData().then(function () {
           console.log(1); //This is running before console.log(0);
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. console.log(1) is actually a plugin init function that would search the appended html and apply an equal height. Somehow this init function has to be called in setTimeout for html that is loaded from ajax. I'll just stay with setTImeout since it is working.

Comment: @user2734550 - If you create a question with the real code in it and the real circumstances, we could probably solve the problem and remove the `setTimeout()` hack.

Comment: The "promise anti-patter" link you provided explains really well. Thanks.